# How to install Hadoop on MacOs?

Tags: java, macos, hadoop

I have MacOs when I install Hadoop I used this Command `sudo apt install hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager`

I got below error

> Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt"

Answer (score 1):

*apt* is the Debian / Ubuntu Linux package management system. What makes you think that MacOs supports Debian packages?!

Instead you could install and use the *brew* package manager.

See https://isaacchanghau.github.io/post/install_hadoop_mac/ for example.

Comment: Also, [Hadoop does not yet support Java 11](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-15338)